# UnityWebRequest Post function doesn't work?

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine, http-post

I am trying to make a Post request using the UnityWebRequest class.
Everything works well if I use this:

```
IEnumerator Loginplayer_old()
{
    print("Login");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", Login_Field_name.text);
    form.AddField("password", Login_Field_Password.text);
    WWW www = new WWW("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form); 
    yield return www;
}
```

But if I use the Post function like this it doesn't work at all:

```
IEnumerator Loginplayer_old()
{
    print("Login");
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", Login_Field_name.text);
    form.AddField("password", Login_Field_Password.text);

    UnityWebRequest www =  UnityWebRequest.Post("http://localhost/sqlconnect/register.php", form);

    yield return www;
}
```

What should I do to get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to send it if using `UnityWebRequest`, it is not automatic:

```
yield return www.SendWebRequest(); // not simply yield return www
```